How to use multi-line comment shortcut in Keil 5?
I've been trying to find the multi-line comment shortcut key in Keil 5 for a while, but I can only manually comment out multiple lines of code. I asked an AI language model, and it told me to find "Edit > Advanced > Comment Block," but in Keil, I can only find "Edit > Advanced > Comment Selection," which seems to be for single-line comments.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me resolve this issue and explain how to use the multi-line comment shortcut in Keil 5. Thank you very much in advance!

A Google search suggests <Ctrl> + / for single line comment // and <Shift> + <Ctrl> + / for /* ... */ block comments. Does that work?

Here is the trick that did it for me, go to edit->configuration, then select shortcuts and search in these options for "Edit:Advanced:Comment Selection" and create your own shortcut for it, for mine, I did the ctrl +/.
